# How can I redirect pan gesture events to parent views?

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have a `UIScrollView` inside a sliding `UIView`. The sliding `UIView` should be able to reach the top of the navigation bar, and if the user is still dragging their finger, the `UIScrollView` inside should start to slide upwards as well. Likewise, if you slide the `UIScrollView` down and you reach the top of the content, the sliding `UIView` should start to slide down.

I can't get this behavior to work the way I want it to. I am specifically using Xamarin.iOS library, but I can translate Objective-C into C# if someone can just point me in the right direction with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be able to do this with a custom delegate and the use of the `scrollViewDidScroll:` method.

In this method check to see if you have reached the bounds of the UIScrollView... if you have then pass whatever variables you need to to the delegate (which is the UIView) and the UIView will handle this information in the way you want.

Example:

UIView.m

```
[self.myScrollView setScrollDelegate:self];
```

ScrollView.h

```
@protocol ScrollViewDelegate : <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)scrollViewDidScrollToEnd:(needed parameters here);

@end
```

ScrollView.m

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if ( [HAS REACHED END OF CONTENT] ) {
        // Here we want to pass the scrolling position to the delegate
        if (!!scrollviewdelegate && [scrollviewdelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollViewDidScrollToEnd:)]) {
            [scrollviewdelegate scrollViewDidScrollToEnd:(needed parameters here)];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the sliding UIView should slide inside the bounds of its superView. Secondly, when sliding the UIView, gestures of the scrollview should be failed until Sliding UIView is at top or at bottom of its superview. These can be done by implementing shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer method of UIGestureRecognizer protocol.

Here I uploaded a [sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3kuyyr08v75mulj/NotToTop.zip?dl=0). The scrollview inside is a tableview.