# Switching to UIPanGestureRecognizer when TableView reaches it top

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uistoryboard

I have a UITableView added to UIViewController. Behind that TableView there is UIImageView like this:
[image]

The default behavior of a UITableView is to show whitespace when scrolling up and there is no more content to show. I would like to override this and switch to custom UIPanGestureRecognizer that will move the whole tableview down.

To clarify: When the tableview reaches it top I would like to move the entire tableview instead.

I have set up my PanGestureRecognizer and added it to the tableview and tried this:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if self.tableView.contentOffset.y == 0{ //tableview reaches its top
            panGestureRecognizer.enabled = true
        }else{
            panGestureRecognizer.enabled = false
        }
    }
```

This does not work at all since the the `scrollViewDidScroll` triggers at the end of the gesture.

Any other ideas on how I can implement this?

Comment: Please refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26357155/4016786).